# 2012 Fiat Scudo van 2.0JTD 128PS

Tags: clutch, fiat

I have a manual box fiat Scudo van and the clutch is ridiculously heavy! I have never driven a vehicle with such a heavy clutch. It works fine but is slowly wearing out my knee joint. When driving it, it doesn't slip nor drag once fully depressed and behaves just like it should apart from this really heavy pedal action. Could anyone suggest a way to rectify this so it doesn't render me a cripple?!

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue with a truck driver, he had a bad knee and a superb employer.

The solution we came up with was to fit a brake servo to the hydraulic clutch and that reduced the effort required so he could continue driving - made him happy and the boss as well.

But you might need to consider a brake servo that can be fitted remote but there may be other solutions.

Have you had the clutch cover plate replaced - is it the original? Has the behaviour suddenly changed? All worth checking - perhaps a replacement is needed.

Comment: I've had the van for a year and a half and it has always been the same. As far as I know, all the equipment is original.